# Searching Twitter likes using keyword

Tags: twitter

The end goal is to exclusively search my own Twitter likes using keywords.

I'm having a hard time figuring out if it's possible via the API and if so, which search that I need (Standard, Premium or Enterprise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it directly. Neither the [advanced search](https://twitter.com/search-advanced) nor the [premium search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview/premium) allow you to limit a search to "User's favourites".

The best you can do is [get all your favourites](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-favorites-list) using `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/list.json` and then search them yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I did find alternatives that do not involve the API: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-ways-to-search-my-Twitter-favorites. The TweetDeck approach specified here seems to work as I wanted and is inexpensive. FWIW.

Comment: The recent changes to Twitter's API mean you can't use the [`get favorites list`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-favorites-list) **v1.1** endpoint on the [`free`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/x-api/developer-account1#:~:text=Free%3A%C2%A0%20Only%20has%20access%20to%20v1.1%20Media%20Upload%20and%20Login%20with%20X%C2%A0) tier anymore; it's just not available.

Comment: Your best bet is to either upgrade to the `basic` tier at $100/month for access to the [`get users id liked tweets`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/likes/api-reference/get-users-id-liked_tweets) **v2** endpoint, or use a workaround with tools like [`twitter-likes-exporter`](https://github.com/mlschmitt/twitter-likes-exporter) to pull your likes.